# Run a function only when another one is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this function and I want to add `.hidden` class only when the div had scroll to top. I know I can use `SetTimeout` but it would be random and I want to be sure that the div disappear when had scroll to top.

```js
$(".more").on("click", function() {
  $("#wait").animate({
      scrollTop: 0
    }),
    $(".more").toggleClass("nascosto"),
    $("#wait").toggleClass("hidden")
});
```

```css
.more {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
#wait {
  font-size: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
#about {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=more>click</div>
<div id="wait">
  <div id=about
  ">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div></div>
```

Comment: Did you read the documentation of [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)? Your answer is there.

Comment: you need to use callback function for animate()....check this...http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the jQuery documentation on `.animate()`, you will see that you can provide a `complete` function.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

> complete Type: Function() A function to call once the animation is
>   complete, called once per matched element.

Comment: Thanks guys I'll have a look :)